# Tensorflow Training has error KeyError: 'Like'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I keep getting an error in my adaptation of this Tensorflow tutorial? I took the example on their site, used my data set and changed the field I am trying to train the programme from. I have checked that the CSV spreadsheet and the code are identical. The column is "Like” column which contains “yes” and ‘no”.

I tried changing the “yes’ and “no” to 1 and 2, but that did not work and I am so new to programming that I have run out of ideas. I just don't understand where I have gone wrong as it appears identical to the example, but with a change to the "key field".

```
ds = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train, batch_size=10)()
for feature_batch, label_batch in ds.take(1):
  print('Some feature keys:', list(feature_batch.keys()))
  print()
  print('A batch of Like:', feature_batch['Like'].numpy())
  print()
  print('A batch of Labels:', label_batch.numpy())
```

Here is the error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22420/4226531187.py in <module>
      3   print('Some feature keys:', list(feature_batch.keys()))
      4   print()
----> 5   print('A batch of Like:', feature_batch['Like'].numpy())
      6   print()
      7   print('A batch of Labels:', label_batch.numpy())

KeyError: 'Like'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess your dataframe before of using in model. Suppose you have a csv file which contains a column 'Like' (values - yes,no) as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("/content/GoogleDrive/MyDrive/yes_no example - Sheet1.csv")  # my sample csv
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    Name    Like
0   Mohan   yes
1   Shyam   no
2   Renu    yes
3   vivek   yes
4   sohna   no
```

you can define a function to convert the string into numeric and can map this function to dataframe column:

```
def liking(yes_no):
  if yes_no =='yes':
    return 1
  elif yes_no== 'no':
    return 2

df.Like = df.Like.map(liking)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    Name    Like
0   Mohan   1
1   Shyam   2
2   Renu    1
3   vivek   1
4   sohna   2
```